# How to create unsigned integers with a length of 256bit in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, types, bitwise-operators, uint

Need to perfom bitwise operations like bitwise not, or, and, etc. on unsigned integers with 256 bit length.
Is there a lib for that?

Was using numpy to create unsigned integers, but the biggest uint datatype is 64.
But now i need to create datatypes like int24 and uint256. Numpy does not support those types.

Comment: Python supports variable-sized integer. Numpy however support native integers (up to 64-bits on most hardware) and pure-Python object type (which are quite inefficient).

Comment: thanks @JérômeRichard. But python only uses signed integers. I need to use unsigned integers and do those bit-operations on them.

Comment: I do not think this is a problem as variable-sized integers are a superset of both fixed-sized unsigned and fixed-sized signed numbers. Low level arithmetic will be very close and higher-level arithmetic can be emulated. Do you have a specific example in mind where you think it could be an issue ?